# Ping a host and display result on a leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation, leaflet, gis

I'm on a web mapping end of studies project, I'm using leaflet for js, I need to ping a host, and display result on leaflet popup, I mean, when a host is down a leaflet popup shows up.
got this php query found on google

```
<?php

$str=exec("ping -n 1 -w1 $ip,$res,$rev);
if $rev==0{
echo ("up");
}
else
{
echo ("Down");
?>
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you noticed you're missing a quote terminator on the exec command? And also missing a ';' on the second 'echo'. Your code should not execute...

Comment: i've tried, still not working, i need to display a popup on leaflet when a server is down!

Comment: What work have you done on the Leaflet side of things? What's the relationship between the hosts and their geographical location?

Comment: every host got a latitude and a longitude, if a host is down, a popup shows up with it's latitude and longitude.thanks